# When importing bundle into existing, working React project I get 'React is not defined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron, bundle

I've tried no fewer than 50 ways to bundle this and they all result in either: `React is not defined` or `react is not defined`.

My `webpack.config.js` to bundle my component library currently looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/test.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'testing.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'umd react',
    'react-dom': 'umd react-dom',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I'm importing it into an Electron-Renderer which uses React itself, but all possible bundler configs fail with those errors still, unless I set `window.React = React` in the consuming project.

I also tried `commonjs`, `commonjs-module`, prefixing `externals` with `umd`, no prefixing of `externals` object-style `externals`, and countless other things.

In the consumer I've tried specifying aliases for these like:

```
alias: {
    react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
    'react-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-dom'),
}
```

I've scoured the web and found the config I currently have works for virtually everyone, but not for me and nor have any others worked. I've chatted this over with GPT4 and Claude.

I've tried everything I can think of and all I can change is the casing of `React/react` in the error message. What else can I try?

Comment: Not an answer, but I decided to stop trying to bundle this and instead just added an exception so that Babel and Typescript loaders will process the source files of this particular dependency.